# Sending mail to gmail in laravel on live server(Hosting:Hostgator) SSl is disbled what should i write in Mail_encryptionn

Tags: laravel, email

I have POP3 account set up with the email account I have on hostgator it is verified as i got mail in my inbox in my email account registered with hostgator....here is the .env file setting
 **.env file**

```
>       MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
>       MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
>       MAIL_PORT=587 
        MAIL_USERNAME=my email address 
>       MAIL_PASSWORD=email password
        MAIL_ENCRYPTION=none //as SSL is disabled
```

> **In the mail.php** the "FROM" address is the info@domain.com..

```
SSL is disabled in my site so what should i use as MAIL_ENCRYPTION and MAIL_PORT
```

kindly help if someone faced the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the port. `587` is `tls`, `465` is `ssl`. In your case, you'd want to set `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to `tls`.

Formally, Google requires all Gmail connections be encrypted, but there may be workarounds.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/G6rE7PFX4rM